# ffmpeg join multiple audio with acrossfade filter

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have audio file multiple:

```
001.ogg, 002.ogg, ..., 100.ogg
```

I need join the files with overfade filter between they.

I did it two in two a cumulative way:

```
ffmpeg -i 001.ogg -i 002.ogg -filter_complex acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri -b:a 128k -o r01.ogg
ffmpeg -i r01.ogg -i 003.ogg -filter_complex acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri -b:a 128k -o r02.ogg
ffmpeg -i r02.ogg -i 004.ogg -filter_complex acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri -b:a 128k -o r02.ogg

....
ffmpeg -i r98.ogg -i 100.ogg -filter_complex acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri -b:a 128k -o final.ogg
```

But `final.ogg` does not have good sound on the firsts songs (less quality while more cumulative).

How can I avoid less quality in the `final.ogg`?

Other way is concat but: How do you define the filter acrossfade using concat?

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.ogg|2.ogg|...|100.ogg" copy final.ogg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in one command using a filter_complex. e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.ogg -i 2.ogg -i 3.ogg -i 4.ogg
 -filter_complex
      "[0][1]acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[01];
       [01][2]acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[02];
       [02][3]acrossfade=d=3:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri"
 -b:a 128k final.ogg
```

Comment: Code works like a champ. I changed a little naming to make it more readable.